# looping over xml_nodeset in R

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping and R. I have been trying to build a function that will scrape multiple items from a each node with a particular name. In my search for an answer I came across https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/12 which has given me a good start.

Here is my question. I use:

```
   nodes <- "http://pyvideo.org/category/50/pycon-us-2014" %>%
   read_html %>%
   html_nodes("div.col-md-6")
```

to give me a xml_nodeset. If I use:

```
    html_node(nodes[1],xpath = "div[1]//a") %>% html_text()
```

I get the information I am looking for. So I need a way to loop over my sml_nodeset and apply the above function, however I have been unsuccessful.

I originally tried to just use

```
    column <- function(x) nodes %>% html_node(xpath = "div[1]//a") %>% html_text()
```

like the link at the top did. But I get an error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : No matches" I have also tried using xpathApply, but it said 
"Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "xml_nodeset""

Any direction you could give me would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It will give you all the titles and links for each video:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

nodes <- "http://pyvideo.org/category/50/pycon-us-2014"
doc <- htmlParse(nodes)
titles <- xpathSApply(doc,"//div[@class='col-md-6']//strong/a", xmlValue)
links <- paste("http://pyvideo.org", xpathSApply(doc,"//div[@class='col-md-6']//strong//@href"), sep ="")
```